# Spinner in navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to retrieve the selected items from the spinner after the restarting app.As spinner contains in navigation drawers,setselection method in sharedpreferences is not working..how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:Solved Problem**
I restored spinner position (stored in sharedprefs) in onDrawerOpened method of navigation drawer..then it worked

Answer (score 0):

You save anything you want inside the onsavedinstance method and retrieve the data in onresumesavedinstance or oncreate.

```
  override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    val spinner : Spinner
    outState.putInt("spinnerselected",spinner.selectedItemPosition)
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

}

override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    if (savedInstanceState!= null){
        val position = savedInstanceState.getInt("spinnerselected",0)
    }
```

This is just an example how to do it. You should have a variable for spinner already Ready from which you can retrieve the data you want and you should retrieve the data from the bündle in the oncreate method after you initialized the Spinner and set it according to the data you retrieved